# How to find the number of dwellers in a room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I want to know the maximum number of dwellers that can be assigned to a particular room. How can I know this? 
At this point of time I'm determining it by continuously assigning until dwellers start replacing each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the vault entrance, all rooms can hold two dwellers per square.

A one-square room holds two dwellers. A two-square room holds four dwellers. A three-square room holds six. The vault entrance takes two squares, but only holds two dwellers.

When you click on a room, there is a clipboard in the lower-left-hand corner. When you click on it, a pop-up menu will show you the dwellers assigned to the room. At the top of the menu, you'll find the number of dwellers currently assigned to the room and the number it can hold, expressed as a ratio.

Here is the room menu for a one-square room with no dwellers assigned to it.

[image: pop-up room menu]
[image source](http://venturebeat.com/2015/06/15/fallout-shelter-makes-living-in-a-postapocalyptic-bunker-adorable-and-totally-free/)

Comment: Except for the vault entrance.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yeah, I guess that's true. The vault entrance takes up two squares but only holds two dwellers.